# Use .bind() on a function and set some parameters as constant but not others, JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know this is possible using basic closures, but I want to see how to do it with .bind() to better understand this function method. See this example code:

```
function add (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var addTwo = multiply.bind(this, 2);

addTwo(10); // returns 12
```

This appears to work fine. However, is it possible to use .bind() to do the same thing, but set the second parameter to a fixed value, while leaving the first parameter untouched?

I attempted the following:

```
function add (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

var addThree = multiply.bind(this, null, 3);

addThree(10); // returns 10, presumably because null + 10 === 10
```

Is there a way to pick and choose which parameters to set and which to leave using .bind() ?

Comment: Funny enough, this was actually something that C++11 aimed for with its own implementation of `bind`. It's not something that could easily be done in a more dynamic language though.

Comment: That's not [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application), that's just partial application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`_.partial`](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) does achieve this with `_` as the placeholder, i.e. `addThree = _.partial(multiply, _, 3)`; [its implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L4217) involves keeping track of the positions of the partial placeholders. While it is a great read, it does involve a library. It is currently the closest thing to having positional argument binding in JS.

Comment: This looks great, thank you. It just doesn't have an option to modify the context for 'this' like .bind does

Comment: Chain it: `_.bind(_.partial(...), this)` (actual syntax may differ)

Comment: @jmancherje: Either `_.partial(multiply, _, 3).bind(this)` or `_.partial(multiply.bind(this), _, 3)` should work.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), no:

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments *preceding* any provided when the new function is called.

<sup>(*Emphasis* mine.)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[No.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) Neither in [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind).

After all, any value (such as `null`, `undefined`, …) in JavaScript can be used as argument for a function. In order to do something like this, you would need something similar to C++11's [`std::placeholders`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders).